# How can i use logical OR for json array response

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, karate, web-api-testing

I have a scenario where response of a API is JSON array. Below i have given an example of JSON response where 'test' is key which is available across the array. So i have to write to Feature step where i should validate the value with both null and regular Expression within a single step. If i am verifying to reg exp and the value is null or vice verse. Step is getting failed.

**For Ex:**

```
* match each $..test== '#regex ^[ A-Za-z0-9-]*$'                                                                                                           
* match each $..test== null
```

I have tried with the below step but it is getting failed.

```
* match each $..test== '#regex ^[ A-Za-z0-9-]*$' | test == null


"response": [
{
   "test": "Anand07"

},{
   "test": null
},{
   "test": "Archu06"
}]
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Code:

```
Feature: Validation

    Scenario:
        * def isValid = function(x){ return x == null || karate.match(x,'#regex ^[ A-Za-z0-9-]*$').pass }
        * def response =
            """
            [
                {
                    "test": "Anand07"
                },
                {
                    "test": null
                },
                {
                    "test": "Archu06"
                }
            ]
            """
        * match each response[*].test == '#? isValid(_)'
```